# Read Simple JSON file (almost done)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a input and when I load it shows the file right in console.log.

But how do I get the actual json data from the file??

```
 $('#importFlow').change(function () {
    var files = event.target.files;
    var file = files[0];
    console.log(file);
    console.log(JSON.parse(file)); //doesn't work

});
```

Comment: What's not working exactly? And can you show us the file ?

Comment: I think doing JSON.parse(file.toString('utf8')); should work... Can you verify?

Comment: You'll need to use the `FileReader` API Check out the docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader)

Comment: it's trying to parse the actual file object not the data

Comment: the file is just a normal something.json file with some json inside

Answer (score 3):

You'd need to use the FileReader API.

```
$('#importFlow').change(function () {
    var files = event.target.files;
    var file = files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(event) {
        var jsonObject = JSON.parse(event.target.result);
        console.log(jsonObject); // Logs the parsed JSON
    }

    reader.readAsText(file);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read actual file content like this:

```
$('#importFlow').change(function () {
    var files = event.target.files;

    var reader, fileContent;
    if (this.files)
    {
        reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e)
        {
            fileContent = e.target.result;                            
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    }
});
```

In the above code, you can get the actual file data in the "fileContent" variable.